# Canvas make event activate when mouseover specific coordinate

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouseover, event-listener

So what I want to do is make it that when I mouseover the canvas somewhere around (340x, 100y) it will run whatever I tell it to do inside.

```
    ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    });
```

All I have is that above, and I don't know how to make it use a specific coordinate.

Also while I'm at it, how could I make the same thing happen but with an entire array?

Thanks ahead of time for any helpful suggestions.
Oh, and I'm NOT using JQuery. JUST Javascript and HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to drop the `ctx` from your event handler like so:

`canvas.addEventListener`

Then I would use the `mousemove` event handler:

```
//This is to get the position of the canvas to (better) accurately
//reflect the mouse coordinates assumes NOT nested in a div or wrapper

var canvasPos = {
    x: canvas.offsetLeft,
    y: canvas.offsetTop
 };

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){

    var mousePoint = {
        x: e.pageX - canvasPos.x,
        y: e.pageY - canvasPos.y
    };

    if(mousePoint.x == 340 && mousePoint.y == 100){

       //do whatever it is you want your code to do

    }

});
```

I hope this works for you or gets you on the right track!! Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddle_me_this/k7drc29b/

Comment: **One necessary refinement:** the browser reports event coordinates as floating point numbers so the odds of a user moving exactly over [340.0000, 100.0000] is very small. Perhaps give at least a 5 pixel range for your hit-testing

Comment: @maddoga feel free to mark the answer correct :). Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `clientX` and `clientY` property to detect co-ordinate.If you want to do somthing with your canvas when mouse over (400,400) co-ordinate you can do it using clinetX/clientY;

> how could I make the same thing happen but with an entire array

If you want to do do it with an `array`( ***if you mean checking for multiple co-ordinates***),you have to create an array of object holding different co-ordinates.

```
      var x=[30,45,50];  // define desired X co-ordinates
      var y=[40,50,75];  // define desired Y co-ordinates
      var coObj=[];   // an empty array to hold all possible (x,y) co-ordinates

       x.forEach(function(el,index){
             coObj.push({x:el,y:y[index]});  //create an array of objects and insert them to coObj array
       })

       canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){

            var xpos=event.clientX-this.offsetLeft;  //here this refers to current canvas object
            var ypos=event.clientY-this.offsetTop;


            for(i=0;i<coObj.length;i++){
                 if(xpos==coObj[i].x && ypos==coObj[i].y){  // check for possible co-ordinate match
                     alert('coOrdinate found !!');
                     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
                 }
            }
       });
```

Comment: You must also adjust for the canvas offset versus the top-left of the document.

Comment: clinetX/y gives actual mouse co-ordinate without offsetting .I've made a fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/spo5no6L/

Comment: as my answer shows below, you need to drop the `context` on the handler as well.

Comment: i directly copied this portion from his code .thanks for pointing it out

Comment: the real problem with clientX/Y here is that your top left is not a (0,0) coordinate. Also `mousemove` is a better choice of `event` bc it will update the coordinate as you move, rather than just when you ENTER the area. ex: of `mousemove` http://jsfiddle.net/fiddle_me_this/spo5no6L/1/

Comment: ok,i have made some edits,taking all possible situations into account

Comment: Thanks you helped me out a lot too!